# How to find the normalization factor of the eigenvectors of the $\sigma_x$ Pauli gate?

Tags: quantum-gate, mathematics, textbook-and-exercises, pauli-gates

I'm trying to calcaute the eigenstates for the $\sigma_x$ gate, and I can follow the process up to finding eigenvalues $\pm 1$, but I don't understand where the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ coefficient comes from for the answer:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda & 1\\
1 & -\lambda
\end{bmatrix}v = 0 \implies v = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

For the solution $\lambda = 1$, why does that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ show up?

Answer (score 4):

The $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is the normalization constant to make sure the state/eigenvector is a unit vector.

Note that: if $|\psi \rangle = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $ then $\bigg| \bigg| |\psi \rangle \bigg| \bigg| = |1/\sqrt{2}|^2 + |1/\sqrt{2}|^2 = 1 $.

The reason for this is because in quantum mechanics, states are always normalized. It is one of the [postulates of quantum mechanics](https://theory.physics.manchester.ac.uk/%7Ejudith/AQMI/PHYS30201se1.xhtml).

Comment: Forgot about the normalization part. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It is normalized by dividing with the modulus or magnitude which is sqrt of (eigenvalue1 * 2 + eigenvalue2 * 2) = sqrt(2)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. What do you mean by *eigenvalue1* and *eigenvalue2*.